# I can install an application but I don't see its icon in the set of installed applications(on the emulator)

Tags: java, android

Hey, When I load an application(which I just compiled) in the emulator. I don't see its icon in the icons of the installed application(on the emulator). The command "adb install ..." tells me that the application is successfully installed(I can even uninstall it with "adb uninstall ..." command). The application is nothing more than a "Hello World"  type of application, you get when you create a project with "android create project --target ...." command. I can compile and run other application perfectly with the same set of tools.

Give me some pointers, what am I missing? what have I overlooked? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` intent-filter in your manifest?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. 
Here is a portion of the androidManifest.xml file...

<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: In your `<application android:icon="">` portion set to the correct image?

Comment: Hey, It was very late at night and I went to bed... I did not manually set the icon image("android create project..." command did it for me). Here is that application element line which you mentioned from the AndroidManifest.xml file... <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">. As per my understanding the value of attribute android:icon="@drawable/icon will be resolved with the help of file R.java and here is the related portion of that file... public static final class drawable {public static final int icon=0x7f020000;}

Comment: For some odd reasons, the things are working now. I can see the skeleton application icon on the emulator and the application works. Falmarri, thankyou very much for your time. If I'm able to find out what I was doing wrong, I'll put it here. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing of creating new projects, when you specify that you want the Android Project creation wizard to create an activity for you, the intent information will be in the manifest file and you shouldn't have this problem.

If you do not choose to create a project with an activity then you will have to remember to add in this intent information to your manifest manually. The intent info should look something along the lines of:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyAppName"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```